# Better ways to reference multi-level pointers?

Tags: c++, visual-c++, pointers, memory, visual-studio-2012

As for now I'm trying to make a basic "fly mode" for a game where such one does not exist. For that I need to manipulate the game memory, and that means that pointers will have to be used to access the memory (from withing a DLL).

As for now I use this code:

```
#define AddVar(Type,Name,Address) Type& Name = *reinterpret_cast<Type*>(Address)
AddVar(unsigned int,gameBaseAddress,0x0089CDA8);//base address

//*Reveal* pointer, dunno how to name this
#define RevPointer(addr,type) (*(type *)(addr))

void FrameTick(IDirect3DDevice9 * device, HWND wnd)
{
    DirectXFont::Access(0)->Print(0.0,0.0,0xFFFFFFFF,"{FFFF0000}N{FF00FF00}F{FF0000FF}S {FFFFFF00}MOD {FF00FFFF}1.0",true);
    if(gameBaseAddress)//check if the game has loaded <accessing the VALUE at gameBaseAddress)
    {
            //lvl 1 ptr
        unsigned int BaseAddr = RevPointer(gameBaseAddress+0x20,unsigned int);//base + pointer offset 1 (+0x20)

            //lvl2 ptr
        BaseAddr += 0x20;//(base + offset 1 (+0x20)) + pointer offset 2 (+0x20) - X pos
        unsigned int PosXAddr = RevPointer(&BaseAddr,unsigned int);//got this line of code by trial and error, don't know how this magicly works
        BaseAddr += 0x4;//y pos is 4 bytes further
        unsigned int PosYAddr = RevPointer(&BaseAddr,unsigned int);
        BaseAddr += 0x4;//z the same
        unsigned int PosZAddr = RevPointer(&BaseAddr,unsigned int);

        float *PosX = (float*)PosXAddr;
        float *PosY = (float*)PosYAddr;
        float *PosZ = (float*)PosZAddr;
        if(PosXAddr && PosXAddr < 0xAAAA0000)//check if pointer is valid
        {
            DirectXFont::Access(0)->Print(0.0,60.0,0xFFFFFFFF,string_format("%.2f %.2f %.2f",*PosX,*PosY,*PosZ).c_str(),true);//works
        }
    }
}
```

From debugging thegame I found out that all pointers are.. well.. multi level pointers:

(((base_adderss + 0xOFFSET1) + 0xOFFSET2) + 0xOFFSET3)...

However this way, it will become very inconvienient to manage all these adresses and offsets.

What I'm doing here in this code is accessing the game's base address, add the first offset to the pointer, then from that pointer I pply the X Y Z offsets (+0x20 , +0x24, +0x28) to get the XYZ position of the wanted object from memory.

This code looks already ugly..
Are there better ways to accomplish what I want to do?

---

Thank you all for the input. If anyone wants the current code I have:

```
#define AddVar(Type,Name,Address) Type& Name = *reinterpret_cast<Type*>(Address)
AddVar(unsigned int,PositionBaseAddress,0x0089CDA8);//base address

struct Point { float x, y, z; };

void FrameTick(IDirect3DDevice9 * device, HWND wnd)
{
    DirectXFont::Access(0)->Print(0.0,0.0,0xFFFFFFFF,"{FFFF0000}N{FF00FF00}F{FF0000FF}S {FFFFFF00}MOD {FF00FFFF}1.0",true);
    if(PositionBaseAddress)
    {
        auto BaseAddr = *(unsigned int*)(PositionBaseAddress + 0x20);
        if(IsBadReadPtr(&BaseAddr,0x04) != 0)
            return;
        auto& p = *(Point*)(BaseAddr + 0x20);
        auto& v = *(Point*)(BaseAddr + 0x70);
        if(IsBadReadPtr(&p,0x04) != 0)
            return;
        DirectXFont::Access(0)->Print(0.0,45.0,0xFFFFFFFF,string_format("Position: %.2f %.2f %.2f",p.x,p.y,p.z).c_str(),true);
        DirectXFont::Access(0)->Print(0.0,60.0,0xFFFFFFFF,string_format("Velocity: %.2f %.2f %.2f",v.x,v.y,v.z).c_str(),true);
    }
}

/*
Position.X: (0x0089CDA8 + 0x20) + 0x20
Position.Y: (0x0089CDA8 + 0x20) + 0x24
Position.Z: (0x0089CDA8 + 0x20) + 0x28
Velocity.X: (0x0089CDA8 + 0x20) + 0x70
Velocity.Y: (0x0089CDA8 + 0x20) + 0x74
Velocity.Z: (0x0089CDA8 + 0x20) + 0x78
*/
```

then I realised I could make clever use of the structs..

and I have made this code:

```
#define AddVar(Type,Name,Address) Type& Name = *reinterpret_cast<Type*>(Address)
AddVar(unsigned int,PositionBaseAddress,0x0089CDA8);//base address

struct Point { float x, y, z; };

struct VehicleInfo
{
    Point Pos;
    int unknown[0x11];
    Point Velocity;
};

void FrameTick(IDirect3DDevice9 * device, HWND wnd)
{
    DirectXFont::Access(0)->Print(0.0,0.0,0xFFFFFFFF,"{FFFF0000}N{FF00FF00}F{FF0000FF}S {FFFFFF00}MOD {FF00FFFF}1.0",true);
    if(PositionBaseAddress)
    {
        auto BaseAddr = *(unsigned int*)(PositionBaseAddress + 0x20);
        if(IsBadReadPtr(&BaseAddr,0x04) != 0)
            return;
        auto& info = *(VehicleInfo*)(BaseAddr + 0x20);
        if(IsBadReadPtr(&info,0x04) != 0)
            return;
        DirectXFont::Access(0)->Print(0.0,45.0,0xFFFFFFFF,string_format("Position: %.2f %.2f %.2f",info.Pos.x,info.Pos.y,info.Pos.z).c_str(),true);
        DirectXFont::Access(0)->Print(0.0,60.0,0xFFFFFFFF,string_format("Velocity: %.2f %.2f %.2f",info.Velocity.x,info.Velocity.y,info.Velocity.z).c_str(),true);
    }
}
```

Comment: Atleast someone tell why he/she wants the question to be closed ;> I've been searching all over the net and couldn't find anything appropriate on this topic / in this case.

Comment: `RevPointer(&BaseAddr,unsigned int)` expands to `*(unsigned int *)(&BaseAddr)`, which is just a round-about way of saying `BaseAddr`. You may as well have written `…PosXAddr = BaseAddr; …PosYAddr = BaseAddr + 4; …PosZAddr = BaseAddr + 8;`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's start by simplifying the arithmetic:

```
unsigned int BaseAddr = *(unsigned int*)(gameBaseAddress + 0x20) + 0x20;

float* PosX = (float*)(BaseAddr);
float* PosY = (float*)(BaseAddr + 4);
float* PosZ = (float*)(BaseAddr + 8);

…string_format(…*PosX,*PosY,*PosZ)…
```

(Note that this skips the `RevPointer(&BaseAddr,unsigned int)` step. See my comment to the original question for why.)

From that, we can further simplify thus:

```
struct Point { float x, y, z; };
auto BaseAddr = *(unsigned int*)(gameBaseAddress + 0x20);
auto& p = *(Point*)(BaseAddr + 0x20);
…string_format(…p.x,p.y,p.z)…
```

I wouldn't bother with the `AddVar` and `RevPointer` macros. They only serve to confuse matters, IMO.

Comment: could you also add an example what it would like if there was a pointer in between the 2 pointers (3 offsets instead of 2)? Then I will accept, this is soo much better, however the validity check (by which I can track the state of the game - loaded / not loaded) I have to do now like this: `if(!IsBadReadPtr(&p,0x04))` which I know is bad but SEH is also bad.. so I'm left without much choice :P

Answer (score 0):

for traversing headers, i've found it useful/concise to use a combination of `auto`, a custom offset type template (which carries the type of the result pointer), and an `operator+` that takes a pointer and said offset type.

i think that will at least be an improvement on your current macro scheme

but i'm not sure if there really is a good way at all to get the code *acceptably* clean. perhaps one must just accept some dirtyness when handling structures with offsets.

---

Ah, I found the code where I used that, in a text file for an earlier SO answer… Unable to find the project though. But here's the code, showing both how to define such offset type and operator, and how it looks in "real" usage:

```
#include <assert.h>         // assert
#include <stddef.h>         // ptrdiff_t
#include <sstream>
using std::ostringstream;

#undef UNICODE
#define UNICODE
#include <windows.h>

template< class Result, class SomeType >
Result as( SomeType const p ) { return reinterpret_cast<Result>( p ); }

template< class Type >
class OffsetTo
{
private:
    ptrdiff_t offset_;
public:
    ptrdiff_t asInteger() const { return offset_; }
    explicit OffsetTo( ptrdiff_t const offset ): offset_( offset ) {}
};

template< class ResultPointee, class SourcePointee >
ResultPointee* operator+(
    SourcePointee* const            p,
    OffsetTo<ResultPointee> const   offset
    )
{
    return as<ResultPointee*>( as<char const*>( p ) + offset.asInteger() );
}

int main()
{
    auto const pImage =
        as<IMAGE_DOS_HEADER const*>( ::GetModuleHandle( nullptr ) );
    assert( pImage->e_magic == IMAGE_DOS_SIGNATURE );

    auto const pNTHeaders =
        pImage + OffsetTo<IMAGE_NT_HEADERS const>( pImage->e_lfanew );
    assert( pNTHeaders->Signature == IMAGE_NT_SIGNATURE );

    auto const& importDir =
        pNTHeaders->OptionalHeader.DataDirectory[IMAGE_DIRECTORY_ENTRY_IMPORT];

    auto const pImportDescriptors = pImage + OffsetTo<IMAGE_IMPORT_DESCRIPTOR const>(
        importDir.VirtualAddress //+ importSectionHeader.PointerToRawData
        );

    ostringstream stream;
    stream << "I'm loaded at " << pImage << ", and I'm using...\n";
    for( int i = 0;  pImportDescriptors[i].Name != 0;  ++i )
    {
        auto const pModuleName = pImage + OffsetTo<char const>( pImportDescriptors[i].Name );

        DWORD const offsetNameTable = pImportDescriptors[i].OriginalFirstThunk;
        DWORD const offsetAddressTable = pImportDescriptors[i].FirstThunk;  // The module "IAT"

        auto const pNameTable = pImage + OffsetTo<IMAGE_THUNK_DATA const>( offsetNameTable );
        auto const pAddressTable = pImage + OffsetTo<IMAGE_THUNK_DATA const>( offsetAddressTable );

        stream << "\n* '" << pModuleName << "'";
        stream << " with IAT at " << pAddressTable << "\n";
        stream << "\t";
        for( int j = 0; pNameTable[j].u1.AddressOfData != 0; ++j )
        {
            auto const pFuncName =
                pImage + OffsetTo<char const>( 2 + pNameTable[j].u1.AddressOfData );
            stream << pFuncName << " ";
        }
        stream << "\n";
    }

    MessageBoxA(
        0,
        stream.str().c_str(),
        "FYI:",
        MB_ICONINFORMATION | MB_SETFOREGROUND
        );
}
```